# Randomize grid items in 4x4 grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if there is any way, using as little JS as possible, to randomize the quantity, size, and placement of grid items in 4x4 grid in accordance to a set of rules whereby the grid is always fully populated without any empty cells:

- A grid item's width or height cannot be less than 50% of its corresponding dimension
- A grid item's area cannot exceed 9 squares

I imagine this could be done by using JS to execute an algorithm that generates the layout of the grid and appends an appropriate amount of children.

Below is an example that uses only HTML and CSS, which is the closest example that I have been able to find so far. However, the Codepen has a predefined quantity of grid items, each of which has a predefined size, and there is always empty cells.

```js
const
  button = document.querySelector(".shuffle"),
  grid = document.querySelector(".grid")

if (button && grid) {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (var i = grid.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      grid.appendChild(grid.children[Math.random() * i | 0])
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  counter-reset: boxes;
}

.tall {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.wide {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.square {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .wide {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  counter-increment: boxes;
  
  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    display: block;
  }
 
  &::after {
    content: counter(boxes);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.blue {
  background: #4040e7;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.red {
  background: #db3c3c;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.green {
  background: #3ddb3d;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.shuffleWrap {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="shuffleWrap">
  <button class="shuffle">Shuffle order of boxes</button>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box red square"></div>
  <div class="box red square"></div>
  <div class="box green square"></div>
  <div class="box green square"></div>
  <div class="box blue square"></div>
  
  <div class="box red wide"></div>
  <div class="box green wide"></div>
  <div class="box blue wide"></div>
  
  <div class="box green tall"></div>
  <div class="box blue tall"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```js
// Function to generate random number between min and max (inclusive)
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// Function to create a grid item with specified dimensions
function createGridItem(row, col, width, height) {
  const gridItem = document.createElement('div');
  gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
  gridItem.style.gridColumn = `${col} / span ${width}`;
  gridItem.style.gridRow = `${row} / span ${height}`;
  gridItem.textContent = `${width}x${height}`;
  return gridItem;
}

// Clear the grid container
const gridContainer = document.getElementById('grid-container');
gridContainer.innerHTML = '';

// Generate a randomized array of possible grid item sizes that meet the requirement
const sizes = [];
for (let i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
  for (let j = Math.ceil(i/2); j <= i; j++) {
    if (i * j <= 9) {
      sizes.push({ width: i, height: j });
      if (i !== j) {
        sizes.push({ width: j, height: i });
      }
    }
  }
}

// Randomize the order of the sizes array
for (let i = sizes.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [sizes[i], sizes[j]] = [sizes[j], sizes[i]];
}

// Function to check if a grid item can be placed at the given position
function canPlaceItem(row, col, width, height) {
  for (let i = row; i < row + height; i++) {
    for (let j = col; j < col + width; j++) {
      if (i > 4 || j > 4 || occupiedCells[i - 1][j - 1]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// Function to mark the cells as occupied by a grid item
function occupyCells(row, col, width, height) {
  for (let i = row; i < row + height; i++) {
    for (let j = col; j < col + width; j++) {
      occupiedCells[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
    }
  }
}

// Function to fill in the remaining gaps in the grid
function fillRemainingGaps() {
  for (let row = 1; row <= 4; row++) {
    for (let col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
      if (!occupiedCells[row - 1][col - 1]) {
        occupyCells(row, col, 1, 1);
        const gridItem = createGridItem(row, col, 1, 1);
        gridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
      }
    }
  }
}

// Fill the grid with grid items 
let occupiedCells = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => Array(4).fill(false));
for (let size of sizes) {
  let placed = false;
  for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= 10; attempt++) {
    let row = getRandom(1, 4);
    let col = getRandom(1, 4);

    if (canPlaceItem(row, col, size.width, size.height)) {
      occupyCells(row, col, size.width, size.height);
      const gridItem = createGridItem(row, col, size.width, size.height);
      gridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
      placed = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
// Fill in the remaining gaps in the grid
fillRemainingGaps();
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="grid-container"></div>
```